# Scheduled run not running even though it was set up correctly?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I've added a `schedule` block to my pipeline that backs up my RDS database. This is the main yaml file for the pipeline, and yaml validator finds no errors. So why is it not running? Nothing shows up in `Scheduled Runs` section in the UI, and I actually waited 3 hours for it to run, to no avail. What am I missing?

```
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
variables:
  - template: ../global-vars.yml

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: self
      type: git
      name: Deployment
      trigger: none
      schedules:
      - cron: "0 */3 * * *"
        displayName: DB backup every 3 hours
        branches:
          include:
            - master
        always: true

stages:
  - stage: DBBackup
    displayName: DB Backup
    jobs:
      - template: /templates/db/backup.yml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property schedules which can be placed in resources > repositories > repository according to YAML syntax documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines

You can add schedules on the top level of YAML

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/schedules-cron?view=azure-pipelines
try something like this sample

```
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
variables:
  - template: ../global-vars.yml

schedules:
- cron: "0 */3 * * *"
  displayName: DB backup every 3 hours
  branches:
    include: master 
  always: true

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: self
      type: git
      name: Deployment
      trigger: none

stages: (...)
```

Comment: That did indeed work, I don't know why I thought it had to be under something. Thanks!